# how to get template working in django?

Tags: django

I was on the 3rd tutorial of this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/ site. I got stuck where we load template for our views under the section `Write views that actually do something`.

The first code is working fine ( as there is no template loading):

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse

 from polls.models import Poll

 def index(request):
     latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
     output = ', '.join([p.question for p in latest_poll_list])
     return HttpResponse(output)
```

But when I laod the template with code below it shows same result as above( that is
with  no template)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader
from polls.models import Poll
def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')

    context = Context({
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The template use is:

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
<ul>
{% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
    <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The template is in polls/template/polls/index.html where polls is my app( as used in tutorial)

PS:I have followed everything as it is till this point from tutorial.

Comment: what's the error message and what does your folder structure look like ?

Comment: @bchhun There is no error its just that loading template makes no difference as i said above. The folder structure i have wriiten in the end

Comment: Are you sure it works without the return statement given in the tutorial?

Comment: The return statement should be on the view not the template. I find it hard to believe there are no errors

Comment: @karthikr which return statement 1st code or the second??

Comment: I moved the return statement from the view file to the second index function :) it wasn't at the right place in the beginning

Comment: Second. I think bchhun fixed the error for you.

Comment: @sashasami I'm pretty positive about your View function throwing an error without the return statement at the end. Try using the example just below with the shortcut function `render`

Comment: @bchhun I am sorry but what did you change ??

Comment: @sashasami the return statement in the second index function was at the end of your template file. I merely cut & pasted the return statement into that function.

Comment: @bchhun But there is a return statement at teh end ,am I missing something?

Comment: @sashasami it wasn't there earlier. Look at the edits => http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17166805/revisions

Comment: @bchhun oh got it. But I have written correctly in code, its just that i might have been careless while formatting on stackoverflow

Comment: @bchhun  sorry for trouble found the mistake, I had 2 index fuctions in views.py , but I am suprised it did not throw an error for that, anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader), django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader looks for template files in a directory named **templates** inside the app directory.

You said that your template is in "polls/template/polls/index.html", but it should be in "polls/templates/polls/index.html" (notice the added **s** to templates).